# UISearch starts before complete search term entered

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate, ios9.1

This is my code:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)va textDidChange:(NSString*)text  {

NSPredicate *predicate;

//  what are we searching for?
if(doExactSearch == NO) {
    if( [oSearchByISBN isSelected])
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isbn contains [c] %@", text];
    else if( [oSearchBySKU isSelected])
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sku contains [c] %@", text];
    else if( [oSearchByTitle isSelected])
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title contains [c] %@", text];
    else if( [oSearchByAuthor isSelected])
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author contains [c] %@", text];
    else  {
        CommonMethods *cm  = [[CommonMethods alloc] init];
        [cm showAlertView:@"Error" message:@"You must choose the field to search on"];
    }
}
else if(doExactSearch == YES)  {
    if( [oSearchByISBN isSelected])
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isbn == %@", text];
    else if( [oSearchBySKU isSelected])
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sku == %@", text];
    else if( [oSearchByTitle isSelected])
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@", text];
    else if( [oSearchByAuthor isSelected])
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author == %@", text];
    else  {
        CommonMethods *cm  = [[CommonMethods alloc] init];
        [cm showAlertView:@"Error" message:@"You must choose the field to search on"];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the *exact* search starts before the user has entered the complete search term (if *exact* is checked).  How do I prevent this?

Comment: Use `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:`.

Comment: HI Rick... and what do I put in there?  All of the code that I now have in *textDidChange*?

Comment: You put whatever code you want run when the user taps Search after entering text into the search bar.

Comment: Thanks... works like a champ!  You want points? Make it the answer!  :D